# How to run separate test for each of the folders in VSCode?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pytest

I am doing a code challenge. So, I download each of the challenges in the main folder. In VSCode, I have opened the main folder.  The test is stuck/limited to the first test I ran. Is it possible that the test looks for test files in each of the sub folders and run according to which file is open.

Bascially, my folder is `code`. Each of the challenges is:

- ~/code/1
- ~/code/2
- ~/code/3

My test is stuck at `~/code/1/1_test.py`. How can I set VS code to pick the test based on the file which I working on?

EDIT: I forgot to mention, I know how to change it. But for each test I need to manually change it by selecting the folder where the test is. Instead I want to know if it can be set to look of `pwd` of the active file and look for test in the current `pwd`.

launch.json:

```
    {
        // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
        // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
        // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
        "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [
            {
                "name": "Python: Current File",
                "type": "python",
                "request": "launch",
                "program": "${file}",
                "console": "integratedTerminal"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: You could open only that subfolder as current folder. Or use a plugin for test management, like Test Explorer (a bunch of them available)

Comment: How are running this "_test_"? If it is from a debug/launch configuration, please also post the contents of your _launch.json_ file.

Comment: @GinoMempin I have added the `launch.json` to the main post. I run the test by opening the test tab on left-side.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is, because that *launch.json* configuration should work. When you open *code/1/1_test.py* in the editor, then click on the *Debug and Run* button, then select that launch config from the dropdown, then VSCode is going to run *1_test.py*. If you open *code/2/2_test.py* on the editor, and re-run the same launch config, it's going to run *2_test.py*. When you switch back to *1_test.py* and re-run the same launch config, it runs *1_test.py*. It works as expected, by running the currently opened file in the editor.

Comment: Using VSCode>Open Folder, I have opened `code`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically there isn't a way such that you keep your project structure the way you want. If you switch to a multi-root workspace you may be able to set up a `launch.json` configuration which takes into consider the directory name to construct the format you want. Otherwise your best option is to simply treat each challenge as their own project and thus having their own settings.