# VS Code. Run several tests that located in different folders

Tags: python, testing, visual-studio-code, python-unittest

I don't understand how to organize my test files in my project with VS Code.

I have some .ipynb files in root from which I run some libs. Currently, I have only one package (lib1) with modules with test for each of them. But If I want to use another package (lib2) from my root where I want to locate my other tests. So, how can I use python unittest in VS code to run several test files in different folders?

In another similar topic was mentioned that launch.json may be used but I can't figure out how to define it.
[How to run separate test for each of the folders in VSCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59469798/how-to-run-separate-test-for-each-of-the-folders-in-vscode)

My current launch.json file has such a structure:

```
{
    "python.testing.unittestArgs": [
        "-v",
        "-s",
        ".",
        "-p",
        "*_test.py",
        "-t"
    ],
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.unittestEnabled": true,
    "jupyter.jupyterServerType": "local" 
}
```

And there is no any way to add additional python.testing.unittestArgs options.

Could anyone give me advice on how to organize the custom libraries and their tests in VS Code?

Answer (score 0):

The paramters in settings.json `python.testing.unittestArgs` are the same as in `python -m unittest discover`. So you can get help on their meaning and usage by running `python -m unittest discover --help`.

I have a similar project setup with multiple modules in different folders and configured `-s` to point to their common root directory.

My working scenario:

```
"python.testing.unittestArgs": [
    "-v",
    "-s",
    "./src/opt/",
    "-p",
    "*_test.py"
],
```

finds test cases in

```
./src/opt/a/a_test.py
./src/opt/b/b_test.py
```

Answer (score 0):

python -m unittest discover --help has this helpful note:

```
For test discovery all test modules must be importable from the top level directory of the project.
```

Putting the `__init__.py` markers in my test folders resolved this issue for me:

```
ls -R ./tests
unit

./tests/unit:
__init__.py     configuration   managers

./tests/unit/configuration:
__init__.py     test_config.py

./tests/unit/managers:
__init__.py     test_manager.py
```